# Jersey + GZIP encoding

Tags: java, rest, jersey, gzip

First of all, I've seem a couple of examples that ilustrate how to use GZIP compression with Jersey.

Although, I saw none that attends the system requirement that I'm developing because I´m using Jersey 1.6 and the Jersey changes drastically from 1.9 to 2.0. Allied of that, all complete examples that I saw are in Jersey 2.0.

Searching for a complete example under 1.9 or less, I found that configuration that was to be places at `web.xml` file.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I think that I have to do something more to allow the GZIP compression.
Note: I have also a welcome file configured.

EDIT: this is my complete `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">
    <display-name>app</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.app.controllers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>hotel-application.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- BEGIN Spring Security Config -->
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- END Spring Security Config -->
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you test your servlet? You have to have `Accept-Encoding:gzip` in the header. If you test your web services in a browser, the chances are the browser unzips everything and shows it to you. Try this: `curl -H Accept-Encoding:gzip -i -u user:pass http://your/web/service`